# composer require appzcoder/laravel-admin: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: php, laravel-5.8

I am trying to run this command in laravel 5.8 but it's not working.

```
composer require appzcoder/laravel-admin
```

and prompts with these statements:

```
     composer require appzcoder/laravel-admin
Using version ^3.1 for appzcoder/laravel-admin
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for appzcoder/laravel-admin ^3.1 -> satisfiable by appzcoder/laravel-admin[v3.1.0].
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - appzcoder/laravel-admin v3.1.0 requires illuminate/support ^5.5 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9].
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.5.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.16|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.17|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.2|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.28|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.33|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.34|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.35|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.36|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.37|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.39|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.40|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.41|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.43|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.44|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.6.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.1|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.10|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.11|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.12|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.13|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.14|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.15|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.16|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.17|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.19|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.2|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.20|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.21|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.22|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.23|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.24|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.25|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.26|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.27|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.28|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.29|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.3|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.30|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.31|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.32|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.33|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.34|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.35|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.36|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.37|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.38|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.39|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.4|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.5|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.6|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.7|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.8|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.9|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.7.17|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.7.18|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.7.19|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.7.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.1|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.10|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.11|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.15|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.2|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.20|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.21|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.22|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.23|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.26|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.27|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.28|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.3|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.4|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.5|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.6|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.7|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.8|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.9|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.8.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.11|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.12|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.14|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.15|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.17|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.18|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.19|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.2|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.20|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.22|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.24|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.27|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.28|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.29|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.3|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.30|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.31|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.32|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.33|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.34|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.35|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.4|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.8|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.9|don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v6.5.2, required as ^6.2) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v6.5.2].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Answer (score 0):

The package is not supported in Laravel version 6.